# Data Grid - Format contents to show neat way

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using datagrid of two columns on a list of fields which has property of field name and field text (input box)

My output looks ugly. Can I get some suggestions to format it neatly.

xhtml:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <p:panel header="Field List">
    <p:dataGrid columns="2" layout="grid" value="#{view.displayableFields}" var="currField" id="fapGrid">
      <h:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{currField.name}" />
      </h:column>

      <h:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{currField.value}" />
      </h:column>

    </p:dataGrid>
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

My ugly output:
[image: So Ugly]

Comment: You have one label and output in your code and many in your question. So the code can never reproduce the image, please post an [mcve]... always... hint: put all labels ansd outputs in one grid (try replacimg the grid with a plain html table. Same problem

Comment: The data table is in a panel if that's what you mean to ask. I have edited the code. Please let me know if it helps

Comment: 1: you have a dataGRID in there not a dataTable. 2: No it does not help. 100% of my previous comment is still applicable.

Comment: This is the exact code I'm using to reproduce my problem

Comment: SORRY, my bad, I missed the value and var. Will respond later today with what is all wrong... (you seem to be expecting certain behaviour from the component that it does not do).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know its not expected behavior of that component. Any other ways to show it neatly would do

Comment: Apply explicit widths via css to the label? And the `h:colum`s are useless here.